# Screencasting from IMX6 to Ubuntu PC through network

Tags: ubuntu, qt, gstreamer

How can we do screen cast from the IMX6 screen to Ubuntu PC through network?

I tried the gstreamer commands in ubuntu and the screencasting working perfectly in localhost. I used the following commands,

Server Side : -

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v ximagesrc ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=I420 ! jpegenc ! rtpjpegpay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5555
```

Client Side : -

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=5555 ! application/x-rtp, encoding-name=JPEG,payload=26 ! rtpjpegdepay ! jpegdec ! xvimagesink
```

But in Imx6 the "ximagesrc" is not present. Is there any source element that support screencasting in IMX6?

Is there any other method to do screencast from target to PC?